# Problem with routing in angular to open different menus on the same place

Tags: angular

I'm a newbie in Angular. I have this situation: My HomeComponent has in .html page a "reference" to Appmenucomponent. So, I need to click on different menus ( each a new component) and open on the same place (div), like the HomeComponent.

home.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-appmenu></app-appmenu>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <section class="content-header">
            <section class="content">
                    <h1>Welcome,  {{currentUser.firstName}}!</h1> 
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>             
            </section>
          </section>
        </div>
</div>
```

In the .html of Appmenucomponent I have a link to routing to Menu1Component,but I don't known how to open it on the same "div" of HomeComponent:

menu1.component.html

```
  <li ><a [routerLink]="['/menu1']"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" ></i> Menu 1</a></li>
```

Here is an image what I expect:

[image]

app-routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: ApploginComponent },
  { path: 'menu1', component: Menu1Component},

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

menu1.component.html

```
<p>menu1 works!</p>
```

an then, I have a Login component too, that redirects to HomeComponent, that contains the Menu.

Comment: Put <router-outlet> in your homeComponent.html 's section tag. This will load router-link to router-outlet appropriately.

Comment: I put <router-outlet> and the when I click on menu 1 open but not in the same place of homecomponent. I loose the menu and the other left div.

Comment: Yes. That's your main component where <router-outlet> </router-outlet> goes. And that is your app.componet where you puts all together.

Comment: Share your routing !

Comment: I already updated with routing

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you have to use :

```
<router-outlet">
// and here you can add whatever you want
</router-outlet>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm doing something wrong. I updated my code (homecomponent) to include router-outlet and when I click on menu 1 the message of Menu1.component.html appears in all page and the actual "css" disappears include the menu

Comment: I updated with new code. If you need more, please tell me. But my application flow is: LoginCOmponent -> HomeComponent (that contains MenuComponent). If I click in menu 1 and menu 2 (both components) it will be redirect to the same place of HomeComponent

Answer (score 0):

Check this stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example here the answer of same problem demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But in this example, the menus are in the app.component. In my case I have a login page to manage that appears first and then, redirect to HomeComponent where are placed the menus and the main div.

Comment: If you put your all component template in app.component.html , then in auth.guard you need to redirect to login.html if not logged in, then after login you need to lazy load menu1 and menu2 component . For that you will need to defines lazy- routine-module, for that you can use loadchildren in app-routing-module for menu1 and menu2